# Proportion Table by Group by Year (data table) of Unique Observations

Tags: r, data.table, unique

I have a table that is unique by {id, product type}, and runs by year:

`id    product_type    sex    year`

`1        A            F      2000`

`1        B            F      2000`

`1        B            F      2001`

`1        A            M      2000`

`1        B            M      2000`

`1        B            M      2001`

etc.

I would like to get a proportion table of sex by year (% of male and female customers by year).

This is what I tried,

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(salesdata)
DT[, .(distincts = length(unique(id))), by=list(year,sex)]
```

And it gives me a count of gender by year. How can I get the percentages or proportions of males and females by year?

Comment: How about this? `DT[, table(sex)/sum(table(sex)), by=year]`

Comment: That works however I get two rows per year, I won't be able to tell which is male which is female.

Comment: Fair point. The fast answer it that `female` is first, because it sorts alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks @YannisVassiliadis

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
gmodels::CrossTable(DT$sex, DT$year, prop.t = F, prop.chisq = F)

   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  6 


             | dt$year 
      dt$sex |      2000 |      2001 | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           F |         2 |         1 |         3 | 
             |     0.667 |     0.333 |     0.500 | 
             |     0.500 |     0.500 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           M |         2 |         1 |         3 | 
             |     0.667 |     0.333 |     0.500 | 
             |     0.500 |     0.500 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |         4 |         2 |         6 | 
             |     0.667 |     0.333 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```